# Is the movie showing true events, or Lorraine's lies?

Tags: plot-explanation, atomic-blonde

In Atomic Blonde most of the movie seems to be showing what Lorraine was telling her supervisor.

If Lorraine was lying, would the movie show actual events, or false events she made up?

> Given that Lorraine had to hide her true identity, I wonder whether Percival was framed. Was Spyglass really shot by Percival and then died in the accident, or was it all just Lorraine's cover-up story?

edit: is it possible that some scenes are her story, and some reveal true events?

Answer (score 4):

It seems the movie depicts the events as they've taken place, some evidence for this is the scene where Delphine appears to tell Lorraine some information about Percival (which she denies in the interrogation), as well as Percivals' comment when he realizes she's going to frame him as Satchel. We also see her prepare the false evidence to frame him, which she certainly omitted in the interrogation.

So while it's unclear how much of the context of the scenes, her individual motivations and goals at any given point were accurate (almost certainly most of them were lies), it seems like what we see her doing is what actually happened; Or at least how she remembers them happening.